# Mixing maven Shade with Proguard

Tags: java, maven, proguard, maven-shade-plugin

I am trying to make a complex build with Maven Shade and Proguard. The thing is that I only want to obfuscate my code and some related libraries (declared in the pom as dependencies), more libraries are present in the `pom.xml` but I do not want to process them with Proguard.

My current approach is the following:

1. Use `maven shade` to generate a Jar with the dependencies I want to obfuscate along with my code. (`execution binded to package phase`)
2. Use Proguard to obfuscate the code. (`execution binded to package phase`)
3. Add the missing dependencies (Storm, etc) to the final Jar via a second execution of `maven shade`.  (`execution binded to verify phase`)

The thing is that in the third step (the second `shade`), I get in the final Jar both obfuscated packages and unobfuscated ones.

Moreover, I also tried to rename via `shade` the packages in the first step but the same happens, unobfuscated code along with the obfuscated renamed lives in the fat Jar.

Another thing that I tried is to exclude the unobfuscated packages in the second `shade` but then I do not get any code from the previous steps, only the external libraries.

Any hints or different approaches to be considered?

Comment: can I look at pom.xml ?

Comment: hi, thanks for the interest. Just solved via Proguard configuration this morning. Nevertheless, I think I need to re-study how ```Shade``` plugin works

Comment: I faced many issues with spring and shade while obfuscating using maven-proguard-plugin with multiple module project.  Wish you luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just solved it via Proguard configuration, only including in the obfuscation phase those libraries that I to be obfuscated (using regular expressions for `package` selection).

For example:

`` `-keep class !com.xxx.**{**}, !com.yyyy.*{**} ``

Thanks